# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict) send @ jquery.min.js:4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, https

i am facing issue with my ajax form of my website. it's showing  **jquery.min.js:4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)send @ jquery.min.js:4**

when i upload my dream host server it's working fine but when i upload it fatcow server then it's showing this error .

Dream host server form [here](http://dakshinakashi.tripleshark.com/CONTACT/serviceprovider.html)

fatcow server form [here](http://www.jdrlawnandlandscape.com/employment.html)

my code for the form here

form submit

```
        $("#contactform2").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',              // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url : $(this).attr('action'),   // the url where we want to POST
                data: formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (returndata) {
                  alert(returndata[0]);
                  $("#contactform2").trigger("reset");
                }
            });
        });
```

i am using  jQuery v1.11.2

hope any one help me

Comment: When things are failing for no obvious reason, it makes sense to step back and look for anything unusual at all.  The 2 obvious things that jump out at me as being unusual are: 1) why are you using `async`? 2) Why are you using a 6 year old, well and truly out of date version of jQuery?  I have no idea if either of those are an issue, but as I said, when there is nothing obvious, look at everything strange. Those things are strange.

Comment: Otherwise, how about some basic debugging - what does devtools show? Is the data sent in the POST correct?  What do your server/PHP logs show?

Comment: it's my client site and also try to use the latest jQuery. but no luck

Comment: yes everything ok on dreamhost server but not working fatcow server. after upload it fatcow it showing jquery conflict